# Can a D visa of Switzerland with valid time exactly 90 days be regarded as a long term national visa to Visit Norway?

Tags: visas, switzerland, norway

I am a visiting student from China. I have not obtained my permit yet. My basic information of the D visa:

type: D (Formation Théorique)
valid from 06/02/2024 to 05/05/2024
MULT
Duration of Stay: XXX

I have found on the website of the Immigration Office of Norway that they use entry visa/long-term visa (for people staying over 90 days) to distinguish between different D visas. While having a long term visa you can travel to other Schengen countries, with an entry visa you can only transit through other Schengen countries. In the website of Switzerland, they call the D visa in Switzerland long-term national visa, but the validity they offered was exactly 90 days (from 06/02/2024 to 05/05/2024).

Will it be a problem for me to use the visa for short-time tourism in Norway?

Comment: Can you share a link to where you saw that distinction? The vast majority of D visas allow you to visit any Schengen country.

Comment: @jcaron Actually any long-stay visas does, according to the Schengen Borders Code (it's for residence permit that there is a convoluted definition and some exceptions). And indeed the vast majority of D visas do allow you to visit any Schengen country *because* they are long-stay visas, which is why the OP is right to be unsure about this particular visa.

Comment: The term 'long/short-stay'  is based on the **maximum length** that the visa type allows. short: **up to** 90 days ; long: **up to** 1 year. A type D visa is a long-stay visa that is also called a National visa.

Comment: @MarkJohnson This seems to contradict some of your other comments. Are all type D visas long-stay visas or not? Can a type D visa be issued for stays under 90 days? What counts as a long stay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the website of Switzerland, they call the D visa in Switzerland long-term national visa, but the validity they offered was exactly 90 days (from 06/02/2024 to 05/05/2024).

That seems very dumb. A short stay in the Schengen system is a stay of 90 days or less (originally 3 months). I don't think that's explicitly defined anywhere but that's the threshold used all over the place and it necessarily follows that a long stay is a stay for more than 90 days. Issuing a visa that falls just under that threshold is utterly confusing and calling it a “long-term” visa achieves nothing (it's up to the Schengen acquis/EU law, not to each individual country, to define what's long term).

The important thing from Norway's perspective is that the visa exemption when crossing an external border defined in article 6(1)(b) only applies to “a valid residence permit or a valid long-stay visa”. It doesn't define or mention “national visas” or “type D visas” but it is clearly limited to long-stay visas, which ought to mean visas for stays longer than 90 days.

That said, I don't think that the Immigration Office of Norway necessarily meant to distinguish between different types of D visas, as opposed to simply assuming they would be valid for more than 90 days as national short-stay visas are not foreseen by the Schengen system (otherwise all the requirements and the whole architecture of the regulations would be entirely optional). These would in any case be very rare.

Because of all this it's unfortunately hard to determine how this visa should be treated or guess how border guards might look at it.

Comment: Wild guess, but maybe that visa comes because they were out of days on their Schengen clock

Comment: @NicolasFormichella Maybe but that doesn't really change anything to what I wrote in the answer. Note that limited territorial validity visas are explicitly designed to cover this case, see article 25(1)(b) of the Schengen Visa Code. So Switzerland has a legal tool intended to give them a better solution in this situation, which would entirely avoid the ambiguity of this not-quite-long-stay visa. Again, the whole system is predicated on the notion that there are no other short-stay visas than uniform Schengen visas.

Comment: The existence of the LTV visa also goes to show that the whole system was built around this assumption that all short stays are supposed to be covered by Schengen rules. If you could simply circumvent the 90-day maximum duration of stay by calling the visa a “D visa”, this maximum stay rule would mean nothing. It wouldn't make sense either to provide for a much more restricted visa like the LTV if national visas already covered this situation.

Comment: The three-month D visa here is for entry only, and AFAIK, also practised by other countries. The relevant point should be the duration of stay, which is XXX, and should be interpreted as for long term stay, even though the visa itself does not authorize more than 90 days.

Comment: FWIW the Schengen convention (art. 18) appears to make D visa and long-stay visa synonymous, although it lies in how to interpret visa *for* a stay longer than 90 days.

Comment: A short-stay visa (Schengen Visa, type C) can allow a stay **up to** 90 days. A long-stay visa (National visa, type D) can allow a stay **up to** 1 year. A long-stay visa can therefore be issued for less than 90 days. See: [German student visa is issued for only 2 months: why? and is it a common practice? - Expatriates Stack Exchange](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/20800/17166)

Comment: @MarkJohnson That's a non-sequitur based on a non-authoritative source and a complete misunderstanding of the Schengen system. I already explained why it doesn't make sense to be able to issue short-stay visas for stays under 90 days and how the phrasing of the Schengen regulations corroborates this conclusion. That's what should be disproved if you disagree.

Comment: @xngtng Yes, indeed, the duration of stay is the relevant factor but given the way visas work in Europe (certainly in the countries I know best and in the Schengen system itself), you shouldn't have a visa with a shorter validity than the stay it authorises.

Comment: @xngtng Re: Schengen convention, I didn't remember that but it makes sense, they are indeed synonymous. When the Schengen acquis became integrated in EU law, the notion of A, B, C, and D-type visas disappeared but since the length of stay is what defines long-stay visa, there is no need for a distinction or additional terminology.

Comment: To be perfectly accurate, I am a aware of a few exceptions (for France : the *visa de retour* or the pretend 7-day visa you give before releasing people in immigration detention when you couldn't manage to remove them) but the logic of the Schengen system still demands that it replaces short-stay visas, it cannot really work well otherwise. In that context, issuing visas for 90-day stays is still needlessly confusing (if you won't do a year then at least do 91 days).

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I have inquired the Norway immigration office. But they gave some contradict conclusions. Last week an e-mail sent back to me written "As long as your D visa is still valid, you can use it to travel to Norway as well as other Schengen countries". While today an officer of Norway Immigration Office told me that I cannot travel to Norway by the D visa unless I have a permit. Also he/she seemed not sure about this problem and told me to contact with the border police. However I did not find the way the contact them.

Comment: You are right that issuing a D-visa valid for less than 91 days with the duration of stay written XXX is very confusing. I totally agree that it would be clear if the valid day is at least 91 days. Also, I have found in the social media in China that some students are given a valid time a little bit more than 90 days and some are even less than 90. So perhaps Switzerland does not deal with this problem well.

Comment: @Relaxed  Additionally, I found that those entry visas in Norway are always D visas given only one entry with the duration of stay written 30 or 90. So it is more confusing to me about the visa offered by Switzerland. I have sent an e-mail to the national police immigration service as well as the embassy of Switzerland in China. I have not yet received their reply.

Comment: @ShSh Important is which type of visa you have, that it is valid and that the duration has not been exceeded. For that the uniform visa sticker has a field called **type of visa**. Visas issued based on the Visa Code have either **A** or **C**. **D** is a visa issued based on national law.

Comment: @ShSh COUNCIL REGULATION (EC) No 1683/95 (uniform format for visas): Article 7 *Where Member States use the uniform visa format for purposes other than those covered by Article 5 [Visa Code], appropriate measures must be taken to ensure that confusion with the visa referred to in Article 5 is not possible.* Annex 11. *This box shall begin with the words ‘**type of visa**’. The issuing authority shall indicate the category of visa.*

Comment: @ShSh Usually such visas are designed to let you apply for a residence permit as soon as you arrive and if the permit issued quickly the duration will be moot but it is still confusing and at odds with the logic of the regulations to issue visas with a validity of less than three months. Other countries issue one-year visa even if they require additional formalities. I am not surprised you could not get useful advice from the police or immigration authorities, for it would be confusing for them as well.

Comment: @Relaxed I also sent an e-mail to the Swiss embassy in China. And they told me the national visa issued by a member of Schengen country allows me to travel to other Schengen country. So I think I would travel to Norway with this e-mail from Swiss embassy. That really sucks though. I have spent a lot of time inquiring about my D visa.

Comment: @Relaxed The border police of Norway told me that I can use the D-visa as a Schengen Visa as long as I come back to Zurich before 05.05.